# Proof $f(x)\delta (x)=f(0) \delta(x)$

Tags: education, dirac-delta

How can I prove the following relation?

$$f(x)\delta (x)=f(0) \delta(x)$$

My book says that it arises from:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(x)\delta(x)dx=f(0)}$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Everything with delta function only makes sense when integrated over. If you find two expressions with delta function integrated to be the same thing, then you can conclude that they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

For $x = 0$, trivially $f(x)\delta(x) = f(0)\delta(x)$.

For $x \neq 0$, $\delta(x) = 0$, so $f(x)\delta(x) = 0 = f(0)\delta(x)$.

Comment: You can make an argument that $f(x)\delta(x)$ depends only on the behavior of $f$ at or near $0$, but it's not meaningful to say that $\delta(x) = 0$ for $x\not = 0$, since $\delta$ is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta$ is a distribution, not a function; your first equation means that
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)\delta(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(0)g(x)\delta(x)
\end{align*}
for any (suitably well-behaved) function $g$, where by definition $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\delta(x) = \phi(0)$. And clearly $f(x)g(x)$ and $f(0)g(x)$ agree at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A more rigorous proof would not write the application of $\delta$ as an integral. Using the notation I learnt the proof would look like follows:

Let $X$ be an open set, $f \in C^\infty(X)$ and $\phi \in C_c^\infty(X)$. Then,
$$\langle f \delta, \phi \rangle = \langle \delta, f \phi \rangle = (f\phi)(0) = f(0) \phi(0) = f(0) \langle \delta, \phi \rangle = \langle f(0) \delta, \phi \rangle$$
Since this is valid for any $\phi \in C_c^\infty(X)$ we have $f\delta= f(0)\delta$.